# Ruby Application Webroot Location

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have inherited a ruby application at work and I am fairly new to ruby hosting environments. The application is hosted on a linux server but I am unable to find where the webroot is.

I have looked for /var/www which is the webroot for apache on linux for other applications I have been working with. But that location doesn't exist on this server.

I was looking through the folders on the server and got a feeling that it might be using Nginx+passenger. Could someone point me in the right direction where to look? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which distro are you running? What is the application's name?

Comment: The application is a custom app written by another team. And, how do I find out what distro is the server using? (The server has been setup by the server team and I am trying to figure this application so I cas start making some customizations)

Comment: `cat /etc/issue`?

Comment: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Kernel

Comment: `grep -lir <your.app.name> /etc/httpd`?

Comment: The etc directory doesn't have a httpd file or directory. However it has a nginx director and and nginx conf. It has a root value: root /home/formengine/current/public;

Comment: sounds like it is the document root of your Rails app.

Comment: what is a document root? (sorry to be a pest but I thing I am closer to finding it that before)

Comment: Actually, nevermind my last comment. I think I understood what you meand. I did find the applicaiton at formengine/current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if nginx was installed as a package, the config file will be probably located in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, you might find the global server settings like this:

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/share/phusion-passenger/source/bin/passenger;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby;

    server {
            listen 127.0.0.1:80;
            server_name localhost;

            root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;
    }
    include virtuals/*;
 }
```

If there is just one application it could be specified by the `root` tag `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. In case that you have there many applications, it's probably in `virtuals` folder (you should look for `include`). The name of the folder could be different, but it's something like `sites-enabled` in apache

Answer (score 0):

Enter `nginx -V` to find out if nginx is installed and where the web root is. The configuration for nginx is normally located at `/etc/nginx` but the command will tell you.

If you have another webserver installed (e.g. `nginx -V` returns `command not found`) the process is different.